# Command line for running server

Tags: node.js

I have a Node server which I would like to debug. Once I've started the server

```
node server.js
```

I want to execute functions defined in `server.js` from a command line. The usual Node REPL "blocks" after the server has started.

For example, if `server.js` defines the function `addBlogPost` I want to locally call `addBlogPost()` and observe changes in the database without passing through a GUI.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`repl`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/repl.html) module to create a new REPL instance:

```
repl = require("repl")
r = repl.start("node> ")
r.context.pause = pauseHTTP;
r.context.resume = resumeHTTP;
```

Now inside the REPL you can use `pause()` to call `pauseHTTP()` and `resume()` to call `resumeHTTP()`.